# Einstein frame vs. Matter frame

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

What is the difference between Einstein frame and Matter frame in General Relativity? -A brief comment on each could be useful too.

These two frames were used in this manuscript http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0306438

Comment: By Matter frame, do you mean Jordan frame?

Comment: Do you mean [these frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_and_Einstein_frames)?

Comment: I am not sure about Jordan frame, but these two frames were actually mentioned in this manuscript http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0306438